# Resharper Unit Testing and Karma

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, resharper, karma-runner

I have a karma.config.js in the root of the web application, which has the followings inputs among others:

```
"content/js/libs/angular/angular.js",
"content/js/libs/angular/angular-mocks.js"
```

if I launch my angular tests like:

```
describe('Registration 1st Step', () =>  {

 beforeEach(module('app'));

var $controller; 
var $httpBackend: ng.IHttpBackendService; 

beforeEach(inject(($injector) => {
    $controller = $injector.get('$controller');  
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
}));

describe('registrationCards', () =>  {
    var $scope: Registration.IRegistrationCardsScope;
    var workflow : Workflow.Registration;
    var controller: ng.IControllerService;

    beforeEach(inject(($rootScope, registrationWorkflow) => {     

        $scope = $rootScope.$new();            
        workflow = registrationWorkflow;            
        $controller('stepsManager', {$scope: $scope});
        controller = $controller('registrationCards', { $scope: $scope, registrationWorkflow: workflow});    
      }));

     it('scope should be not null', () =>  {
        expect($scope).not.toBe(null);
     });
});
```

using karma start it works fine by using phantomjs.

if I try to use the resharper unit test explorer, it gives me "Test not Run" with the message of "encountered a declaration exception".

It really seems that it's not loading the karma.config.js, do you have any idea?

Thanks,

Luca

Answer (score 0):

You should add reference to angular.js and angular-mocks.js to each test spec file to resharper can load them. note that resharper not use karma test runner for running tests.
so you should add these lines to start of your code:

```js
/// <reference path="content/js/libs/angular/angular.js" />
/// <reference path="content/js/libs/angular/angular-mocks.js" />
```

also add all files that needed for test to run exactly like this notation (e.g. controller files, service files,..)

Answer (score -2):

Seems that I've found a "partial" solution

http://kearon.blogspot.ch/2014/08/testing-typescript-with-jasmine-in.html

I need to rename all the libraries like angular.js and angular-mock.js to angular.d.js and angular-mock.d.js in the same folder where the definitions are and then must add the reference on each test file.

It can be quite harshy unfortunately...

probabily is better to use chtuzpah..